# Trouble with approach on creating AlertBox in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I want to create an alert box that has a text box and two buttons in it. I created a layout for this consisting of an `EditText` and created a class extending `DialogFragment` class. I have created the `onCreateDialog()` and wanted to send the input from the `EditText` to database. I have the databasehandler class too. I now want to create an object of the class and use the `show()` whenever I need the Dialog to appear.

Is this approach correct or will it be better if I create the `onCreateDialog()` in a class that extends `Activity` rather than creating the object as in the earlier approach?

The code snippet is :

public class AskDialog extends DialogFragment {

```
private String var = "";
EditText ask;

public void setVar(String var){
    this.var = var;
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflator = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflator.inflate(R.layout.ask, null));
    builder.setTitle("Not Found").setMessage("XYZ is not found");
    final EditText ask = new EditText(this); //Error
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ab = ask.getText().toString();
        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Don't Know", new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    return null;
}
```

}

I want to use this class by making an object of this in an Activity class and use its show(getFragment(), null) function.

Answer (score 0):

For making custom alert box you can use 'Layout Inflater' class provided by android. To know more about Layout inflater you can directly check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

I think this code will help you to build a custom AlertBox with Edit field and a Button.

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)Yourclass.this.getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
addNotes = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ask, null);

final Button positiveButton = (Button) addNotes.findViewById(R.id.btn_positive);

final EditText et_ask=(EditText)addNotes.findViewById(R.id.et_ask);

positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

String ab = et_ask.getText().toString();

addNotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
});

LayoutParams params = new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
Yourclass.this.addContentView(addNotes,params);
addNotes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: My problem is if I am trying to instantiate an EditText in my custom Dialog class and want to read the value of that in the setPositiveClick method it is reporting an error. How do I overcome that...?

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply..I edited my answer please go through it.